# .Net WindowsForms MouseDown event not firing

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

As a new user to VB, I am struggling to see why this code works in one project but not in another. This code works fine if I create a new project and 2 new forms but when I place in my project, it doesn't fire at all on either left or right click.

I have tried a try/catch statement, but no errors are being reported. How do I go about troubleshooting this to find out the error. I have tried to rem out code and run after each comment but still the same. I have even tried removing all other code on the form leaving just the 2 subs but no joy. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

frmMain

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'StorageDataSet1.Customers' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.CustomersTableAdapter.Fill(Me.StorageDataSet1.Customers)
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'StorageDataSet.User' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.UserTableAdapter.Fill(Me.StorageDataSet.User)

        'Dim frmDepartmentsLive As New frmDepartment
        'frmDepartmentsLive.Owner = Me
        'frmDepartmentsLive.ShowDialog()


        lblDate.Text = Now

        Timer1.Start()

        rdoCustomer.Enabled = False
        rdoCustomer.Checked = True
        rdoDepartment.Enabled = False
        rdoDepartment.Checked = False

        For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
            If TypeOf ctrl Is Button Then
                AddHandler CType(ctrl, Button).MouseDown, AddressOf btn_MouseDown
            End If
        Next

    End Sub

Private Sub btn_MouseDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)

        If (e.Button = MouseButtons.Right) Then
            Dim btn = CType(sender, Button)
            frmRacks.buttonName = btn.Name.Replace("btn", "")
            frmRacks.Show()
        ElseIf (e.Button = MouseButtons.Left) Then
            MessageBox.Show("To be coded")
        End If
    End Sub
```

frmRacks

```
Public Class frmRacks
    Public buttonName As String
    Private Sub racksfrm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        lblRacks.Text = buttonName

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCancel_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub



End Class
```

Comment: Is the control a child of another control or something?

Comment: @ta no. It is just a button ctrl. thanks

Comment: start by setting a breakpoint on `If (e.Button = MouseButtons.Right) Then` to see if it ever fires, then step thru to see whats wrong

Comment: @Plutonix I set a breakpoint where you suggested and the event does not fire. Thanks

Comment: then the way the event handler is hooked up may be wrong.  If these arent dynamically buttons, try adding the handler directly. or step thru the addhandler loop and see if it is doing what you think

Comment: Start at the beginning - put the breakpoint on the AddHandler line first!

Comment: @PeterG I put the breakpoint directly on the AddHandler, but nothing fired. Thanks

Comment: Then it is never going to work of course.  Otherwise easily explained by these button being located on a panel instead of the form.  Just don't write code like this, your user will never figure out that right-clicking a button is required to display the window.  Create usable UI, use a dedicated button or a toolstrip button.

Comment: @hans Why woud this not work in a panel. It works in a panel when I create new project. The button serves 2 purposes and as such the user is clearly aware what each click does. As a matter of form, I took the buttons outside of the panel and it still didn't work. Thanks

Comment: Because your For Each loop iterates Me.Controls.  Which are the form's controls, not the panel's controls.

Comment: if the buttons are on a panel, then they will be in that panel's COntrols array, not the form's which is what you are looking thru with `Me.Controls`.  Use `thePanelName.Controls` instead.

Comment: @Plutonix many thanks. If you would like to submit as answer, I will gladly accept such. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the controls are on a panel, they are members of that panel's controls array, not the form's.  This -- and other things -- are apparent if you look thru the form's designer (on solution explorer, click Show All, then open `formXXX.designer.vb`).  DOnt change anything, but it shows how controls are created and added.  So...

```
    For Each ctrl In thepanelName.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is Button Then
            AddHandler CType(ctrl, Button).MouseDown, AddressOf btn_MouseDown
        End If
    Next
```

If it is ONLY those buttons on the panel you can short cut it:

```
  For Each btn As Button In thepanelName.Controls
       AddHandler CType(ctrl, Button).MouseDown, AddressOf btn_MouseDown
  Next
```